# Would pressure oscillations at the inlet of a liquid engine turbo-pump subside at the outlet, or would they get amplified?

Tags: engine-design, pressure, turbopump

Would pressure oscillations at the inlet of a liquid engine turbo-pump subside at the outlet, or would they get amplified?

What are the factors that decides the change in the amplitude of pressure oscillation at the outlet?

Answer (score 2):

They *can* get amplified.  That is a contributor to the classic "pogo" resonance phenomenon.

> Another
> rocket
> system
> instability,
> of very low frequency
> (order of a few
> hertz),
> is caused by propellant
> flow rate oscillations which
> result
> from **pump
> amplification
> of
> the fluctuations
> of the pump inlet pressure**
> (the
> pump inlet pressure
> variations
> are due to the
> g-loading
> of the liquid
> column
> extending
> back
> to the tank).

(emphasis mine)

The important factors are listed here.

> PUMPS:
> The
> proper
> treatment
> of pumps
> requires more than just the simulation
> of the head-flow relationships.
> The capacitance
> and inertance
> can be equally important,
> particularly
> in the high-speed pumps used in rocket engine systems.

Source: [LIQUID PROPELLANT ROCKET
COMBUSTION INSTABILITY](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/citations/19720026079)